# Accessing data from database in joomla

Tags: mysql, joomla

I am using this query in Fabrik (Joomla Application) to pull the data from database, which is not working.

The same query with mysql syntax is working fine in `PHPMYADMIN`.

```
$db = FabrikWorker::getDbo(false, 2);

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query
    ->select('hostel_fee')
    ->from('hostel_fee AS a')
    ->join('INNER','students AS b ON (b.class = a.class)');     
$db->setQuery($query);
$a = $db->loadResult();
return $a;
```

Comment: get `echo $db->toString($query);` afetr `setQuery` function returns

Comment: I have tried to get the value of $a using var_dump($a);exit; and I am getting a 'null' value.

Comment: Thanks guys I was able to resolve it using the code below:
$db = FabrikWorker::getDbo(false, 2);

$query = $db->getQuery(true);

$query = "SELECT a.hostel_fee
FROM hostel_fee AS a, students AS b
WHERE b.class = a.class AND b.id='{students___id_raw}'"; 
$db->setQuery($query);
$a = $db->loadResult();
return $a;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the full queries like this

```
$db = &JFactory::getDBO();

$query = "SELECT m.id, m.title,m.level,mt.menutype FROM #__menu AS m

     INNER JOIN #__menu_types AS mt ON mt.menutype = m.menutype

     WHERE mt.menutype = m.menutype AND m.published = '1' ORDER BY mt.menutype,m.level";

$db->setQuery($query);

$rows = $db->loadObjectList();
OR
$rows = $db->loadResult();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this

```
$db = FabrikWorker::getDbo(false, 2);
```

Use this.

```
$db =& JFactory::getDBO();
```

Or if you want to use any external database to connect to your extension you can use this

[Connecting to an external database](http://docs.joomla.org/Connecting_to_an_external_database)

Comment: Since I am using a alternative db connection " $db = FabrikWorker::getDbo(false, 2);" is correct, as I am getting the results with this connection for other fields.

Comment: are you want to fetch the data from the database other than fabrik default?